# Complex addition issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, sum, subquery

I am trying to create a calculated column based on the information from several other columns and this is being quite difficult to me as a new person to SQL. Below is the code I tried to use but it gets mad about the line "Sum(SlotActual + TableActual) As Actual" I am guessing this is due to those being aliases. I think I need to use a subquery but I am not sure as I have not done those before. If possible I would prefer not to even display SlotActual or TableActual I just need to calculate those and then add them in order to get Actual. This is being done in SQL 2008. Please let me know if I have left out any info you need.

```
Select Ltrim(Rtrim(P.Player_ID)) as "Player ID",
Ltrim(Rtrim(P.FirstName)) as "First Name",
Ltrim(Rtrim(P.LastName)) as "Last Name",
Sum(CashIn) as "Cash In",
Sum(CashOut) as "Cash Out",
Sum(Jackpot) as "Jackpot",
Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot end) as SlotActual,
Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn + S.CreditIn - S.CashOut end) as TableActual,
Sum(SlotActual + TableActual) As Actual

From dbo.CDS_PLAYER as P
Join dbo.CDS_ACCOUNT as A
    On P.Player_ID = A.Primary_ID
Join dbo.CDS_STATDAY as S
    On P.Player_ID = S.Meta_ID

Where S.GamingDate Between '09/15/2014 12:00:00 AM' and '09/21/2014 11:59:59 PM'
And P.EntryDate Between '09/15/2014 12:00:00 AM' and '09/21/2014 11:59:59 PM'
And S.IDType = 'P'

Group by Ltrim(Rtrim(P.Player_ID)) ,
Ltrim(Rtrim(P.FirstName)),
Ltrim(Rtrim(P.LastName))
```

Error message I am getting is below:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 3, Line 3
>   Invalid column name 'SlotActual'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 3, Line 3
>   Invalid column name 'TableActual'.

Comment: Please post the error sql is giving you.

Comment: you cannot use an alias in an aggregate function.  sql server does not support this.  Try throwing your whole formula in the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i see the problem now. You cannot reference a select named field like that.

Replace:

```
Sum(SlotActual + TableActual) As Actual
```

Do this instead:

```
(Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot end) +
Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn + S.CreditIn - S.CashOut end)) As Actual
```

To allow for nulls:

```
(Sum(ISNULL(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot end), 0) +
Sum(ISNULL(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn + S.CreditIn - S.CashOut end), 0)) As Actual
```

The [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) allows for a value to be used when the left argument is null.

If your data allows you could also just add an else to your `CASE` giving you a value when `S` does not have any values.

```
(Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot ELSE 0 end) +
Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn + S.CreditIn - S.CashOut  ELSE 0 end)) As Actual
```

Comment: ok this makes sense and gets really close to what I need but there is a catch I forgot to mention. Sometimes the Slot or the Pit will be null. When I tried this variation if one of them was null the whole sum came back null is there a way to error catch null and turn it 0 or ignore it?

Comment: Wrap it in `ISNULL` or `Coalesce`

Comment: With the Else 0 version it worked perfectly. I have one more question to take this a step further should I ask that here or make a new post on that?

Comment: If it is related to this problem you can post it here.

Comment: I missed one of the lines of code earlier when I posted this question. That line reads.  Ltrim(Rtrim(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate))) as Trips,    I am needing to make a new column that is the Actual we just calculate and divide it by the trips. When I tried using a similar concept to what we did here of just including the whole formula for actual and trying to divide by the formula to trips I got an error that stated Implicit conversion from data type varchar to money is not allowed. use the convert function to run this query.

Comment: Take out the trims, it is a count and will return a numeric value, there is no need to trim it. Trim returns a varchar value.

Comment: on a side note about these forums how do I space down a line when adding a comment because when I try to do that pressing enter just posts the comment instead. Because of this I was not able to add the code boxes around the code in my last comment

Comment: Not sure, i don't think comments are meant for large code segments so it may not have the ability to do so.

Comment: Thank you that fixed the issue and I am good to go you guys have made me look like genius to my company and I thank you much. On the point of the comments that is strange so if I needed to respond with modified code I would have to edit the first post or place and answer myself I guess interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Use wrapper like this :

```
select X.*, Sum(ISNULL(SlotActual,0) + ISNULL(TableActual,0)) As Actual
From (
Select Ltrim(Rtrim(P.Player_ID)) as "Player ID",
Ltrim(Rtrim(P.FirstName)) as "First Name",
Ltrim(Rtrim(P.LastName)) as "Last Name",
Sum(CashIn) as "Cash In",
Sum(CashOut) as "Cash Out",
Sum(Jackpot) as "Jackpot",
Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot end) as SlotActual,
Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn + S.CreditIn - S.CashOut end) as TableActual,

From dbo.CDS_PLAYER as P
Join dbo.CDS_ACCOUNT as A
    On P.Player_ID = A.Primary_ID
Join dbo.CDS_STATDAY as S
    On P.Player_ID = S.Meta_ID

Where S.GamingDate Between '09/15/2014 12:00:00 AM' and '09/21/2014 11:59:59 PM'
And P.EntryDate Between '09/15/2014 12:00:00 AM' and '09/21/2014 11:59:59 PM'
And S.IDType = 'P'

Group by Ltrim(Rtrim(P.Player_ID)) ,
Ltrim(Rtrim(P.FirstName)),
Ltrim(Rtrim(P.LastName))
) X
```